# ExpoCLI- IOS Could Not Connect to Server

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have been working on a react native project in Windows 10 for a while now using Expo to scan the given QR code and test the app on my IOS device. The other day I ran $expo start and everything seemed to go fine until I tried to load the app on my IOS device. I received this message:
[Could not connect to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWXMm.jpg)

I then "Run in Web Browser" which worked fine, so I tried accessing 127.0.0.1:19000 in my Iphone's browser (firefox) and it as well could not connect to server. My phone is connected via wifi which is 2.4 or 5g. I wasn't sure how this would effect this so I used a wifi adapter on PC to match which wifi connection phone and PC were on and that didn't help.

I am using react version 17.0.1, expo version 3.28.5, and "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.0.tar.gz"

I have tried:

1. Turning off windows firewall
2. Using different Iphones to connect
3. npm install --global expo-cli
4. Changing Connection from "LAN" to "Local"
5. Reinstalling Node
6. Creating a System Variable called: "REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME" with the value "192.168.2.108". This did change the LAN IP address as intended but it did not resolve the problem. I just got the same message with the new IP address.

This problem just started happening out of the blue and I'm not really sure what to do next. If you need any additional information I'd be happy to give it.

Comment: "So I tried accessing 127.0.0.1:19000 in my Iphone's browser (firefox)" is not going to help you if your RN app is running on your Windows PC; 127.0.0.1 is referring to the local address - in your case the iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use

```
expo start --tunnel
```

Comment: I did that and got this: "Error loading DevTools
ValidationError: "urlType" must be one of [exp, http, redirect, no-protocol]" in the Expo Developer browser screen. The terminal said this: Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL. I will look into this and see if I can get tunnel to work.

Comment: Ok so, when I just did "npm start" and then turned on tunnel it gave me the same error message but then refreshed back to the normal page with tunnel activated. I scanned it with my phone and it is working now! Can you explain why tunnel mode is working but the others arent?

Comment: @ColePerry i thinks  it is problem of @ ip

Comment: could you be a little more specific? Everything is working fine now though thank you.

Comment: I don't know exactly the details ,whene you use tunnel you connct to the internet thne  to app but in lan you conect the locale of your netwerks

Comment: I think using tunnel is going thru the Internet which makes it a bit slower. In my case I had to DISABLE all other Networking Adapters (e.g. VMWare, Hyper-V, etc) before the phone could connect to the Windows PC via WI-FI

Answer (score 0):

When you get the message:

```
"Error loading DevTools ValidationError: "urlType" must be one of [exp, http, redirect, no-protocol]"
```

Just wait for a bit and the QR code for tunnel will appear. It does the same for me as well.